OnDemandAssignmentProvider/OnDemandOrderPlaced event was removed
I am the developer of subscan.
When dealing with coretime related functions, it was found that this event has been removed in the new version (the event also exists in the document https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/polkadot/runtime/parachains/ src/assigner_on_demand/mod.rs#L547).
But there is no such event in the source code. And in the rococo coretime network, this event is no longer included in the place_order_allow_death and place_order_keep_alive transactions.
Why OnDemandAssignmentProvider/OnDemandOrderPlaced events were removed？
We need this event to save data. The actual price cannot be calculated well by relying only on the parameters in the transaction (because the historical traffic parameters(and on_demand_base_fee) cannot be obtained on the chain).
so hopefully this event can be restored.
If possible, it would be better to add account data to OnDemandOrderPlaced

Thanks for asking this! I also happened to stumble upon this issue the other day.
Long story short, I believe this has been removed accidentally and we will add them back, but while we are on it, could you be more specific what events you are actually interested in the most?
Please chime in on the ticket: https://github.com/orgs/paritytech/projects/119/views/20?pane=issue&itemId=60682952
Given that we have to fix it, we can also improve things/make them more ergonomic while we are at it.
E.g.
What kind of events are you interested. That an order was placed/that the price has changed? Is the traffic value useful at all or would you much rather see the actual price directly? ....
Anything else that easy to expose, that would be useful?
